# Client apps are opened in wrong vnc display

Tags: xorg, security, vnc, wayland

I use ubuntu 22.04; gnom(wayland); tightvncserver.

When i open client, like mate-calc, on vncviewer display :3 it pop-up on the console  of the computer (display :0) instead of the vnc viewer display :3

My xstartup file:

```
#!/bin/sh
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
/usr/bin/startplasma-x11
```

The command on the server side:

```
vncserver :3
```

The command on the remote desktop:

```
vncviewer theServerSide:3
```

If I open xterm it will open in display :3 (good), but, if I open mate-calc it will open on the host console.   I think it is a big security problem.  How to avoid this behavior?

This problem does not happen in CentOs7 or CentOs9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to unset the environment variables that are associate with /run/$UID
because I saw there the wayland display.   I found that what I need is to insert to the xstartup, before the window manager command:

```
unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
```